# Express nested routes returning empty params

Tags: javascript, express

I have something like this:

```
localhost:8000/api/news?category=tech
```

I currently have a router for the /api section and another one for /api/news.

But when I try to print req.params in the /api/news router, it's not showing { "category": "tech" } as I thought it would.

Comment: Try using `req.query`. That's not a param, its a query string

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get params then.

```
const handleIt =  ( req,res)=> {
console.log(req.body)
console.log("POSE",req.params)
}
routes.post('/api/news/:category',handleIt)
```

Also call it using

```
localhost:8000/api/news/tech
```

Comment: What is the difference between '/news/tech' and '/news?category=tech'? Reading through some articles on params vs query, I believe the way I'm doing it is better suited for my needs.

Comment: @Latcie cool. My answer contain params as you asked for params in question